# Converting the captured coordinates into yards

Tags: jquery, html, image, coordinates

There is a `div` with a background image with the following style :

```
#cont {
                position: relative;
                background-image: url('./st.png');
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                width: 541px;
                height: 349px;
        }
```

Its background image has height of 349px and a height of 541px. The image is a soccer field. The length of a soccer field is 115 yards and breadth being 75 yards.

To convert the each captured coordinate (using mousemove event) into yards, I did this :

```
x_yard = (115*x1)/541
y_yard = (75*y1)/349

// x1 and y1 are the captured coordinates
```

It gives the incorrect result. `XMax` is near to 116 and `YMax` is near to 69. How could I convert the captured coordinates to yards?

Comment: I'm getting what looks like correct results. Where are you getting `XMax` is 116 and `YMax` is near 69?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles at the extremes.

Comment: What are the extreme `x1` and `y1` values you're getting? I wouldn't think they could be greater then 541 (x, width) and 349 (y, height). E.g., 115 * 541 / 541 = 115. Am I missing something?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles extreme is 116 and 69 as I mentioned earlier.